# Using --whole-archive linker option with CMake and libraries with other library dependencies

Tags: c++, cmake, g++

I've got a project that used to be a giant set of source files that all got compiled and then linked as one executable.  As a first step in making the project more modular, I am breaking up the build into several smaller chunks and making them static libraries. There's a hierarchy, so `Exe1` will link against static libs `Lib2A` and `Lib2B`. `Lib2A` will depend on static `Lib3A`, `lib3B`, `lib3C`, etc.  The numbers here show their layer in the hierarchy.

The problem is that I need to use `--whole-archive` when linking or else some symbols from the underlying libraries are not found.

When I add the below for the linking of `Exe1`:

```
target_link_libraries(Exe1 -Wl,--whole-archive Lib2A Lib2B -Wl,--no-whole-archive)
```

I end up with an actual link stage command like:

```
g++ -o Exe1 -Wl,--whole-archive libLib2A.a libLib2B.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive libLib3A.a libLib3B.a libLib3C.a
```

Inevitably, symbols from some of the layer 3 static libraries get lost and I get missing symbol errors.

I expected that because `Lib2A` has `Lib3*` libraries as dependencies, that they would also be "inside" the `--whole-archive` part of the linker command, but they show up outside.

I've tried many different combinations (e.g. putting the `--whole-archive` stuff at lower layers), but haven't come across an approach that works using CMake.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: static libraries (when building them)  are NOT linked ,only executables (programs and shared libraries) are ! A static library is merely a collection of  object-files.

Comment: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16947

Comment: engf-  Yes, you are correct.  I was misusing the terminology. I'll try to correct the question so it's more accurate.

Comment: @RichardHodges - Using object libraries would alleviate the problem.  Unfortunately, I think having dependencies among object libraries didn't make it into CMake until 3.12 or 3.13?  I'm unfortunately tied to 3.4 for now.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For 3.12 and newer versions of CMake, I would use object libraries.

The workaround I found for versions earlier than that was to create an intermediate static library that used some property magic to place all linkage dependencies inside the --whole-archive section.  For me, the top-level static library was called 'source'.  It contained actually nothing itself, but had linkage dependencies on a bunch of other static libraries.  I created 'source-combined' as follows:

```
add_library(source-combined STATIC "")
set_target_properties(source-combined PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

target_link_libraries(source-combined PUBLIC
  -Wl,--whole-archive
  $<TARGET_PROPERTY:source,INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES>
  -Wl,--no-whole-archive
)
```

Now when I create an executable or a shared library by linking against this souce-combined library, I get the --whole-archive and --no-whole-archive as bookends around the *entire* set of static libraries that were the link dependencies of 'source'.  It took forever to stumble across this technique, so I'm sharing it.

Comment: Could use more info about what "source" is in $<TARGET_PROPERTY:source,INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES>. There's not enough info, at least for me, to understand how to make this work. Also, in my situation, the (static) library in question is built outside CMake.

Comment: @Greg - sorry, that definitely wasn't clear.  'source' in this context came from a project I worked on that created a giant static library from a large source folder hierarchy.  If you tried to create a static library based on 'source', it would link against all of the sub-libraries that source was based on but wouldn't always keep them inside the markers.  'source-combined' was kind of a wrapper around that so that you could use the --whole-archive/--no-whole-archive around the entire 'source' static library without worrying about not having all of the sub-libraries within those two markers.

Comment: In my comment above, I meant to write "if you tried to create a *dynamic* library based on 'source'.."

Comment: There is a typo. It should be `-Wl,--whole-archive` with a single leading minus instead of a double minus.

Comment: I had to use INTERFACE instead of STATIC. With STATIC it complained that no sources were passed. Further, I had to use the hack specified in https://discourse.cmake.org/t/automatically-wrapping-a-static-library-in-whole-archive-no-whole-archive-when-used-during-linking/5883 to get it to work.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to use the linker option `--whole-archive`, then you definably should use object libraries:

```
    # Lib2A/CMakeLists.txt
    add_library(Lib2A OBJECT ${Lib2A_SRC})
```

```
    # Lib2B/CMakeLists.txt
    add_library(Lib2B OBJECT ${Lib2B_SRC})
```

It is portable and does not require use the linker option `--whole-archive`.

Comment: The accepted answer says as much.  Before object libraries were around, though, other options had to be considered.

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me. Consider two libraries:

- my_platform
- my_clib

We want the whole archive of my_clib, and my_platform links to it.

```
add_library(my_platform INTERFACE) # this could also be a regular library

add_library(my_clib STATIC)
target_sources(my_clib
PRIVATE 
    gcc_newlib_nano.c 
    gcc_newlib_nano_cpp.cc 
)

# Link my_clib and any other libs
target_link_libraries(my_platform
INTERFACE
    my_clib
)
# Ensure the whole archive is linked
target_link_options(my_platform
INTERFACE
-Wl,--whole-archive ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libmy_clib.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
)
```

Comment: Nice - this is a slightly more verbose way of doing what my answer does.  The nice thing with your solution is you avoid generator expressions.  I guess a potential downside is that you are referring to my_clib by the filesystem name and not the CMake target name.

Answer (score 4):

CMake 3.24 adds an official way to do this using the [`LINK_LIBRARY:WHOLE_ARCHIVE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#link-features) generator expression:

```
add_library(lib1 STATIC ...)
add_library(lib2 ...)
target_link_libraries(lib2 PRIVATE "$<LINK_LIBRARY:WHOLE_ARCHIVE,lib1>")
```

That being said, using [object libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) is usually an easier solution. That way the list of compiled object files from the library you are linking is simply used as-is in the final linker command, instead of first creating a static library file.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the above answer, I needed to get something quick and dirty to see if the effort to add whole archive target flags (or convert the code base to object libraries...) was the right solution. By following the [CMake Source Code](https://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=blob;f=Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake;h=72b2857db9cf240523f8fd9174f64ddbeb6ecd78;hb=HEAD#l285) for the default link command, I modified my project's command to:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE "<CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER>  <FLAGS> <CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS> -o <TARGET> -Wl,--start-group -Wl,--whole-archive <LINK_LIBRARIES> -Wl,--no-whole-archive -Wl,--end-group")
```

It worked a treat! While not the greatest solution, it will at least get some results quickly.