# Undefined reference in transitive library linking

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a large library `B` that performs some operations on a configuration object `MY_CONFIG`. This library is linked against an even larger library `C` that provides the main functionality. In the end, `C` is linked against the executable `main`.
The configuration object `MY_CONFIG` is unique for each computing unit. Since the goal is to produce one `C` library for all systems, I am currently trying to produce an additional library `A` that only contains the defined configuration object.

In other words, all computing units eventually receive the same `C`, but different `A` libraries.

The problem is, however, that I get an `undefined reference` linker error when trying to link main against `C` and `A`.

Let's illustrate the example with some code:

**A.cpp**

```cpp
#include "B.hpp"

Config MY_CONFIG = {
    .id=2
};
```

**B.hpp**

```cpp
int get_config_id ();

typedef struct Config {
    int id;
} Config;
```

**B.cpp**

```cpp
#include "B.hpp"

extern Config MY_CONFIG;

int get_config_id () {
    Config work = MY_CONFIG;
    return work.id;
}
```

**C.hpp**

```cpp
void print_config();
```

**C.cpp**

```cpp
#include "B.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void print_config() {
    std::cout << "Config ID: " << get_config_id() << std::endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "C.hpp"

int main() {
    
    print_config();
    
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(config)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -pthread")


add_library(A STATIC A/A.cpp)
target_include_directories(A PUBLIC B)

add_library(B STATIC B/B.cpp)
target_include_directories(B PUBLIC B)

add_library(C STATIC C/C.cpp)
target_include_directories(C PUBLIC C)
target_link_libraries(C B)


add_executable(main main.cpp)

# Apparently, this is not possible. But why?
target_link_libraries(main C A)
```

As you can see, I use the `extern` keyword for `MY_CONFIG` in **B.cpp**. My intuition was that it is resolved once building the executable main. Since the definition of `MY_CONFIG` is in `A.cpp`, I also link main against A. The following error shows up during compilation:

```
/usr/bin/ld: libB.a(B.cpp.o): in function `get_config_id()':
B.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `MY_CONFIG'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I linked A against C, then it works perfectly fine. But this is something that I want to avoid because I'd need to deliver individual C's for all computing systems. An important side note: I can only work with static libraries (no shared objects).

Is my intention generally not possible or what do I miss?

Comment: Are you sure your question is consistent? With current version of `CMakeLists.txt` there should be an error about `get_config_id` and not about `MY_CONFIG`.

Comment: @MarekR: The code in the question post produces exactly the error about `MY_CONFIG`. I have reproduced that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake has no issue with circular dependencies between static libraries. Just declare the actual dependencies and CMake will take care of the rest. Here is my revised CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(config)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_library(A STATIC A/A.cpp)
target_include_directories(A PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/A")
target_link_libraries(A PRIVATE B)

add_library(B STATIC B/B.cpp)
target_include_directories(B PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/B")
target_link_libraries(B PRIVATE A)

add_library(C STATIC C/C.cpp)
target_include_directories(C PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/C")
target_link_libraries(C PRIVATE B)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE C)
```

Using your exact sources, I can build and run like so:

```shell
$ cmake -G Ninja -S . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
...
$ cmake --build build --verbose
[1/8] /usr/bin/c++  -I/path/to/B -I/path/to/A -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/B.dir/B/B.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/B.dir/B/B.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/B.dir/B/B.cpp.o -c /path/to/B/B.cpp
[2/8] /usr/bin/c++  -I/path/to/A -I/path/to/B -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/A.dir/A/A.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/A.dir/A/A.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/A.dir/A/A.cpp.o -c /path/to/A/A.cpp
[3/8] : && /usr/bin/cmake -E rm -f libB.a && /usr/bin/ar qc libB.a  CMakeFiles/B.dir/B/B.cpp.o && /usr/bin/ranlib libB.a && :
[4/8] : && /usr/bin/cmake -E rm -f libA.a && /usr/bin/ar qc libA.a  CMakeFiles/A.dir/A/A.cpp.o && /usr/bin/ranlib libA.a && :
[5/8] /usr/bin/c++  -I/path/to/C -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -c /path/to/main.cpp
[6/8] /usr/bin/c++  -I/path/to/C -I/path/to/B -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/C.dir/C/C.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/C.dir/C/C.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/C.dir/C/C.cpp.o -c /path/to/C/C.cpp
[7/8] : && /usr/bin/cmake -E rm -f libC.a && /usr/bin/ar qc libC.a  CMakeFiles/C.dir/C/C.cpp.o && /usr/bin/ranlib libC.a && :
[8/8] : && /usr/bin/c++ -O3 -DNDEBUG  CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -o main  libC.a  libB.a  libA.a  libB.a  libA.a && :
$ ./build/main
Config ID: 2
```

As you can see, the final link line produces `C B A B A`. The latter two don't hurt anything since they'll never actually be searched.

---

If you want to break the cycle, you can break off the part of B that A needs into another library and make both of them depend on it.

Now I have the following files:

```
// A/A.cpp
#include "common.hpp"

Config MY_CONFIG = {
    .id=2
};
```

```
// common/common.hpp

typedef struct Config {
    int id;
} Config;
```

```
// B/B.cpp

#include "B.hpp"
#include "common.hpp"

extern Config MY_CONFIG;

int get_config_id () {
    Config work = MY_CONFIG;
    return work.id;
}
```

```
// B/B.hpp

int get_config_id ();
```

The build is then adjusted like so:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(config)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_library(common INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(common INTERFACE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/common")

add_library(A STATIC A/A.cpp)
target_include_directories(A PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/A")
target_link_libraries(A PRIVATE common)

add_library(B STATIC B/B.cpp)
target_include_directories(B PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/B")
target_link_libraries(B PRIVATE common A)

add_library(C STATIC C/C.cpp)
target_include_directories(C PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/C")
target_link_libraries(C PRIVATE B)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE C)
```

and when we build, we see that the link order is correct and the duplicated libraries have disappeared:

```shell
$ cmake --build build --verbose
[1/8] /usr/bin/c++  -I/path/to/A -I/path/to/common -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/A.dir/A/A.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/A.dir/A/A.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/A.dir/A/A.cpp.o -c /path/to/A/A.cpp
[2/8] /usr/bin/c++  -I/path/to/B -I/path/to/common -I/path/to/A -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/B.dir/B/B.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/B.dir/B/B.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/B.dir/B/B.cpp.o -c /path/to/B/B.cpp
[3/8] : && /usr/bin/cmake -E rm -f libA.a && /usr/bin/ar qc libA.a  CMakeFiles/A.dir/A/A.cpp.o && /usr/bin/ranlib libA.a && :
[4/8] : && /usr/bin/cmake -E rm -f libB.a && /usr/bin/ar qc libB.a  CMakeFiles/B.dir/B/B.cpp.o && /usr/bin/ranlib libB.a && :
[5/8] /usr/bin/c++  -I/path/to/C -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -c /path/to/main.cpp
[6/8] /usr/bin/c++  -I/path/to/C -I/path/to/B -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/C.dir/C/C.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/C.dir/C/C.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/C.dir/C/C.cpp.o -c /path/to/C/C.cpp
[7/8] : && /usr/bin/cmake -E rm -f libC.a && /usr/bin/ar qc libC.a  CMakeFiles/C.dir/C/C.cpp.o && /usr/bin/ranlib libC.a && :
[8/8] : && /usr/bin/c++ -O3 -DNDEBUG  CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -o main  libC.a  libB.a  libA.a && :
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
target_link_libraries(main C A)
```

you could use

```
target_link_libraries(main C B A)
```

which will produce correct order between the libraries in the linker's command line. So you will overcome the "undefined reference" error.

### Explanations

The library `B` uses symbol (specifically, a variable) `MY_CONFIG`, which is defined in the library `A`. So, for link the resulted executable successfully, you need either:

1. Ensure, that `A.a` **comes after** `B.a` in the linker's command line.
2. Use options, which eliminates ordering-sensitivity for the linker.

You could follow the second way by using `-Wl,--whole-archive` option. See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53071878/using-whole-archive-linker-option-with-cmake-and-libraries-with-other-library).

For following the first way, that is ensuring the **order** of the libraries to link, it should be taken into account that CMake provides two ways for enforce ordering:

1. Linkage **between** the libraries:

   ```
   target_link_libraries(B A)
   ```

   This is most convenient and scalable way. It ensures that in the linker's command line `A.a` will come after the **last** `B.a`.

   But this linkage doesn't fit for your purpose.
2. **Order of libraries** in `target_link_libraries`. E.g.

   ```
   target_link_libraries(main <...> B A <...>)
   ```

   will ensure, that **at least one** `B` will be followed with `A`.

   This way has **lesser guarantee** than the first one. E.g. that order doesn't prevent CMake from producing the linker command line `<...> B.a A.a B.a <...>`, which will again cause the undefined reference error. But CMake won't duplicate libraries in the command line without needs.

E.g., instead of

```
target_link_libraries(main C A)
```

you could use

```
target_link_libraries(main C B A)
```

So the linker command line will contain the libraries in exactly that order:

```
ld <...> C.a B.a A.a
```

Note, in the given command line `B.a` follows `C.a`, which correlates with another linkage you have in your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_link_libraries(C B)
```

so CMake won't add another `B.a` into it.

---

The linkage

```
target_link_libraries(C B)
```

which you currently have in your code only ensures that `B.a` will come **somewhere** after `C.a` in the linker command line.

With additional

```
target_link_libraries(main C A)
```

you could expect that CMake produces correct command line

```
ld <...> C.a B.a A.a
```

which satisfies both linkages.

But CMake is perfectly allowed to produce another command line:

```
ld <...> C.a A.a B.a
```

where `B.a` does not immediately follow `C.a`.

Exactly that command line causes the "undefined reference" error in your case.