# Linking OBJECT library to OBJECT library in CMake

Tags: cmake

Project structure: 
[image]

Where `bar` and `foo` are OBJECT libraries, and `foo` is using functions from `bar`. But in final executable there's no symbols from `bar`, only from `foo`. How can I fix it?

Root `CmakeLists.txt`:

```
add_subdirectory(foo)
add_subdirectory(bar)

add_executable(main null.c)
target_link_libraries(main foo)
```

`foo/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library(foo OBJECT foo.c)

target_link_libraries(foo bar)
```

`bar/CmakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library(bar OBJECT bar.c)
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use a `OBJECT` lib here? Which OS are you working on?

Comment: I'm working on Ubuntu 22.04, but I'm cross-compiling software for ARM Cortex M0+ with -nostdlib flag, so using static libraries gives me ELF file without symbols at all

Comment: `--whole-archive` looks like solution, but it produces a lot of cmake code each time when I need to link a library (it's just MRE, full project contains 10+ libraries), so I found suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53071878/using-whole-archive-linker-option-with-cmake-and-libraries-with-other-library) to use object libraries.

Comment: Never tried sth. like this, but here are a few things you could try: 1. Use the `PUBLIC` keyword in the `target_link_libraries` cmds. 2. Linking Object Libraries via `$<TARGET_OBJECTS>`. Check out the cmake documentation [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#linking-object-libraries-via-target-objects) how to do this. 3. Using  `$<LINK_LIBRARY>` like explained [here](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/automatically-wrapping-a-static-library-in-whole-archive-no-whole-archive-when-used-during-linking/5883).

Comment: 1. It doesn't work :(
2. Also doesn't work.
3. Requires CMake 3.24, but my environment has only 3.22.

Comment: + using third approach PUBLIC include directories don't work

Comment: Does the main executable even use a symbol from bar? Maybe there is some optimization going on in the background which you are not aware of. Otherwise, I have no further ideas. You could show the code from the *.c files, possibly there is something wrong.